# Silence the output of a shell command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook

Using Jupyter Notebook, you can run shell commands, for example:

`!ls -l`

Meanwhile, I found myself running a shell utility that has is very verbose and has many lines of talkback as it runs.

As I iterate over this, I will eventually end up with thousands of lines of talkback in the notebook.

I know usually you can silence the output of a cell by using a `;`.  However this won't work:

`!ls -l;`

(this is a dumb example, I know, nobody would probably ever want to silence `ls`)

Is there any way I can silence the output of a shell command in Jupyter notebook? I don't know javascript so I don't think I'd be able to hack something together using that route...

Answer (score 7):

You could always redirect the output of your command to /dev/null

```
!ls > /dev/null
```

This works for me.

Comment: Does it also work on Windows?